# Xamarin Android (PCL) Layout not correctly render in dependency service

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to display a dialog on Android using Dependency Service. However, I could not get the design I create in android layout designer to display, the result comes out is different.

This is the screenshot of my previewer:
[Expected design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9XrR.png)

This is the screenshot of my result:
[Unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv7iq.png)

My axml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialogWrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstyle"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:stateListAnimator="@null">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:text="TitleText"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="subtitle test"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_editTextWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedentry"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="inputText test"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RL_editTextWrapper"
    android:background="#cdced2" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonNO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#007aff"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cdced2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#007aff"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The @drawable/backgroundstyle code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<corners
    android:radius="16dp" />
```

This is the code for exporting dependency service in android:

```
namespace FFF.Droid.Native {
public class IOSDialogStyleDroid : IIOSDialogStyle {
    public void ShowPopup(EntryPopup entryPopup) {
        var context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as FormsAppCompatActivity;
        CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(context) {
            entryPopup = entryPopup
        };

        customDialog.Show();


    }
}

public class CustomDialog : Dialog {
    public Context context { get; set; }
    public EntryPopup entryPopup { get; set; }


    public CustomDialog(Context context) : base(context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestWindowFeature((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.iOSStyleDialog);

        EditText editText = FindViewById(Resource.Id.inputText) as EditText;
        (FindViewById(Resource.Id.title) as TextView).Text = entryPopup.Title;
        (FindViewById(Resource.Id.subtitle) as TextView).Text = entryPopup.Message;
        var btnOk = FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialogButtonOK) as TextView;
        btnOk.Text = entryPopup.okButton;
        btnOk.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            entryPopup.OnPopupClosed(new EntryPopupClosedArgs {
                Button = entryPopup.okButton,
                Text = editText.Text
            });
            Dismiss();
        };
        var btnNo = FindViewById(Resource.Id.dialogButtonNO) as TextView;
        btnNo.Text = entryPopup.cancelButton;
        btnNo.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            entryPopup.OnPopupClosed(new EntryPopupClosedArgs {
                Button = entryPopup.cancelButton,
                Text = editText.Text
            });
            Dismiss();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check how it looks when you are not using a dependency service because I am pretty sure the problem you have is with the XML design and nothing to do with dependency services..

Answer (score 0):

I found out that textalignment seems broken, I use gravity instead.